# Neo4j 5.0.1 and APOC

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

Recently, Neo4j presented 5.0.1 version. Is there a corresponding APOC library available for such release?

Right now I'm unable to start Neo4j 5.0.1 with apoc-4.4.0.9-all.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 5.0, APOC `core` moved to an official repository https://github.com/neo4j/apoc while the non-core and thus not supported by the Neo4j core engineering team is maintained on community effort.

You can download a compatible APOC version for Neo4j 5.1.0 here now https://github.com/neo4j/apoc/releases/tag/5.1.0

Alternatively, APOC is also shipped with the Neo4j Tarball under the labs directory

```
$ ls -la labs/
total 30656
drwxr-xr-x@  5 christophewillemsen  staff       160 Sep 16 14:10 ./
drwxr-xr-x@ 19 christophewillemsen  staff       608 Sep 16 13:17 ../
-rw-r--r--@  1 christophewillemsen  staff     11330 Sep 16 13:17 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--@  1 christophewillemsen  staff      1131 Sep 16 13:17 README.txt
-rw-r--r--@  1 christophewillemsen  staff  15679269 Sep 16 14:10 apoc-5.0.0-core.jar
```

If you're using Docker, you can check here an example `docker-compose` with `APOC` installed https://github.com/ikwattro/neo4j-docker-playground/tree/main/neo4j-5-single

Comment: Thanks for your answer! One more question - how about OGM support for Neo4j 5.x? Will we have OGM version for Neo4j 5.x?

Comment: I cannot comment for the OGM from source but I suppose there will be a new version using the Neo4j 5.1 driver, afaik sdn is already planning for supporting Neo4j 5.

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j APOC has not released a version for Neo4j ver5 or greater. As a starter, neo4j is using Java version 17 while APOC version 4.4.x are still in Java version 11.  Thus, there is a conflicting versions that causes error in starting Neo4j 5.0.1.  We just need to wait for it (APOC 5.x) to be released.